# database only showing zeros 0

Tags: java, php, android

I'm new to java and PHP, could someone please help my database only shows 0's ...

java code:

public class postData  extends Activity {

```
//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//url to update coordinates
private static String url_update_coordinates = "http://www.myurl.com";

//JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "Success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.post_coords);

    final Context ctx = this;

        //Create button
        Button btnUploadCoordinates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        //Button click event
        btnUploadCoordinates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // updating coordinates on background thread
                new UploadCoordinates(ctx).execute();

            }
        });

    }

    //Background Async Task to upload coordinates

    class UploadCoordinates extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {

        // Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        private Context ctx;
        public UploadCoordinates(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(postData.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Coordinates...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Creating Coordinates

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            JSONArray json = new JSONArray();



            MySQLite dbhelper = new MySQLite(ctx);
            Cursor data = dbhelper.getlocations();

            while(data.moveToNext()) {

                int _id = data.getInt(0);
                double latitude = data.getDouble(1);
                double longitude = data.getDouble(2);
                double altitude = data.getDouble(3);
                double speed = data.getDouble(4);
                double timestamp = data.getDouble(5);

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                try{
                jo.put("_id", _id);
                jo.put("latitude", latitude);
                jo.put("longitude", longitude);
                jo.put("altitude", altitude);
                jo.put("speed", speed);
                jo.put("timestamp", timestamp);
                } catch(JSONException e) {

                }

                json.put(jo);
            }
            String json_data = json.toString();


        // Adding the data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coords", json_data));


        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.myurl.com");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Check log for response
        Log.d("Create response", json.toString());
            return null;
        }
```

// check for success tag

> try {
>                         int success = json_data.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

**GIVING ME PROBLEMS HERE**   *The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type String*

```
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSLoggerService.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }


        //After completion background task Dismiss progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
```

}

php script:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');
//include dbconnect class
    require_once  (__DIR__ . '/db_connect.php');

    //connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();     

    //decode array
    $arr = (isset($_POST['coords']));
    $decarr = json_decode($arr, true);

    $count = count($decarr);

    $values = array(); //hold array values so we do one single insert

    $update_values = array(); //holds values for the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

    for ($x=0; $x <$count; $x++)
    {
        $newrec = $decarr[$x];
        $_id = $newrec['_id']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_id);
        $latitude = $newrec['latitude']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($latitude);
        $longitude = $newrec['longitude']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($longitude);
        $timestamp = $newrec['timestamp']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp);
        $altitude = $newrec['altitude']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($altitude);
        $speed = $newrec['speed']; $_id = mysql_real_escape_string($speed);

        //create insert array
        $values[] = "('".$_id."','".$latitude."','".$longitude."','".$timestamp."','".$altitude."','".$speed."')";

        //For the duplicate updates
        $update_values[]=
        "latitude=VALUES(latitude), longitude=VALUES(longitude), timestamp=VALUES(timestamp),                               altitude=VALUES(altitude), speed=VALUES(speed)";
    }

    //insert records
    $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(_id, latitude, longitude, timestamp, altitude, speed)
            VALUES ".implode(',', $values)." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(',',$update_values);

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Been trying for hours and can't figure out where the problem is, maybe this will be a silly one for many of yous out there.

thank you in advance for all your help.

Regards
V

UPDATE - Not sure if I should do this, but it will be easier as all the code is already here, my error is between blockquote... can't get my head around to see where the problem lyes ... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function and assign it's return value to $arr variable, and then using it as an array.

You should use this function to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL: it returns true or false.

In your PHP code, instead of lines 10 and 11, try this:

```
$decarr = isset($_POST['coords']) ? json_decode($_POST['coords'], true) : array();
```